# How to pass RGB tuples to `px.bar`?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

You need [so_sample.parquet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YDI7SDk3HLHFL3iZKwDGL5pgPyE6WmWG/view?usp=sharing) to run the code

I need to replicate this bar plot in plotly, and most importantly be able to preselect the colors randomly in the same fashion.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_parquet('so_sample.parquet')
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().unstack().fillna(0)
df.plot(
    kind='bar',
    stacked=True,
    legend=False,
    xlabel='',
    rot=0,
    color=np.random.uniform(0, 1, (df.shape[1], 3)),
)
```

[image: matplotlib]

Here's what I did so far:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_parquet('so_sample.parquet')
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index(name='count')
px.bar(
    df,
    x='col1',
    y='count',
    color='col2',
).show()
```

[image: p2]

I tried passing `color_discrete_sequence=[color1, color2, ...]` and it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data format used in matplotlib is wide format, but in plotly it is long format. plotly should be the same wide format and you can specify your favorite colormap. I chose Dark24, which has a large number of colors.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_parquet('./data/so_sample.parquet')
#df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().reset_index(name='count')
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).size().unstack().fillna(0)

px.bar(
    df,
    x=df.index,
    y=df.columns.tolist(),
    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Dark24,
).show()
```

[image]

Comment: I need to either know which colors were assigned to which values in `df.columns` or be able to specify colors in the same fashion as matplotlib's. Besides, it seems the colors are being repeated since the top stack (the green one) has the value `-136` in the legend, and its actual value is some 7 figure number, which means there's another green in the stack (the same happens with matplotlib, but I don't like it)

Comment: The colors and column names are shown in the legend, but what else do you mean?

Comment: I need to have the list of colors separately so I can reuse it later elsewhere. Besides, the legend is truncated, so it needs to be in a separate figure or not shown if this is going to be a hassle / there's no direct way to do it

Comment: Naturally, there are 24 colors, so if there are more than 24 colors, the process will be repeated. The colors used here are the following. `['#2E91E5', '#E15F99', '#1CA71C', '#FB0D0D', '#DA16FF', '#222A2A', '#B68100', '#750D86', '#EB663B', '#511CFB', '#00A08B', '#FB00D1', '#FC0080', '#B2828D', '#6C7C32', '#778AAE', '#862A16', '#A777F1', '#620042', '#1616A7', '#DA60CA', '#6C4516', '#0D2A63', '#AF0038']`

Comment: `print(px.colors.qualitative.Dark24)` You can now retrieve it.

Comment: I know, and I checked them right after you posted your answer, the repetition is misleading and as I indicated in question, I need to preselect the colors, or have 99 different colors somehow.

Comment: I'll generate random hex colors then instead of px.colors, I guess that would solve the problem, nevermind then, thanks.

Comment: I don't have a 99 color list so I can't try, but the help says it is a list of letters so it may be possible. Please try it for plotly users.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll generate random hexes instead which should solve the problem